# Passing file to function and parsing data using fgets() and strtok() in C

Tags: c, file, fgets, strtok

I'm doing a C programming assignment where the program has to read data from two files which are passed to the program through the command line and parse the data into separate fields to use in a linked list, probably using strtok(). The function prototype is already provided, which is

```
int loadData(char* menuFile, char* submenuFile);
```

So far, I've opened the files and passed the file data to the function using

```
menufile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
submenufile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
loadData(argv[1], argv[2]);
```

and I'm trying to use fgets() and strtok() to parse the data using a "|" delimiter.

My question is, I assume now that in the loadData() function I've got a pointer to a char array, and I've tried to pass that to fgets() using the following code

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), menuFile)){
    value = strtok(line, "|");
    result[i][0] = strdup(value);
    printf("Category ID: %s\n", value); etc
```

but I get the following:

```
 warning: passing argument 3 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

and a segmentation fault.

How do I use fgets() to treat this data in a meaningful way?

Comment: You need the third parameter to fgets() to be a FILE * -- try using fopen() to open your file and pass the file pointer it returns to fgets as the third param.

Comment: Hi JohnH, I've used fopen() to open the files in main(), but judging by the function prototype that was provided, I'm supposed to pass this data to the loadData() function for parsing. So what gets passed to the function is a char array??? Now I've got to read this data using fgets(). Is this possible, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: It looks like you are passing the wrong arguments to your loadData() function - as JohnH said, the third parameter to fgets() needs to be a FILE* - so instead of argv[1] and argv[2], you need to pass menufile and submenufile to loadData().

Comment: Thanks @rfernandes. I think I sorted it out. It seems that what was passed as "arg[1]" was not the contents of the file, but the filename itself. I was able to use "FILE *fp = fopen("menu.dat", "r");" in the loadData() function after passing "menu.dat" as parameter argv[1] on the command line, and now fgets() can use the file data as intended.

Comment: @SquintonCarbusier I think you are making this harder on yourself than you need to. Just from your problem description, it appears you are supposed to pass the `menu` and `submenu` names to the function and then open your `FILE *` streams within the function itself. Otherwise, your prototype would be `int loadData(FILE* menuFile, FILE* submenuFile);` I would also encourage you to look at `getline` instead of `fgets` (it can allocate memory for you dynamically with lineptr=NULL)

Comment: @ David C. Rankin Yeah, I have a habit of overcomplicating stuff. I've worked this one out, but have hit about 3 other barriers now. C is kinda difficult.